# React Material-Table calling a React Component via table actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have a datatable implementation as followings.

```
<MaterialTable
        icons={tableIcons}
        title={title}
        columns={columns}
        data={data}        
        actions={[
          {
            icon: () => <Edit />,
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => {

            }
          },
          {
            icon: () => <Delete />,
            tooltip: 'Delete',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => {
              return <DeletePrompt button_click="1" /> // <-- this is where I need to call the modal
            }
          }
        ]}
        options={{
          actionsColumnIndex: -1,
          exportButton: true,
          headerStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold"
          }
        }}
      />
```

However, I need to make use of the following modal to implement Delete actions.

DeletePrompt.jsx

```
export default function DeletePrompt(props) {
  const content = props.content;
  const data_id = props.data_id;

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  if(props.button_click === 1){
    handleClickOpen()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
          {"Are you sure to Delete?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            { content }
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} autoFocus>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know that invoking the `handleClickOpen()` method would have worked in this case. But for some reason it doesn't appear to work. Any guess on what I am missing over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering the modal on the button click in the `onClick` method of `Delete` icon, you should set a dialog boolean and also a state variable to hold the data of the selected row data.

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState({});
```

in your `onClick`, you can update the code to below to trigger the boolean flag for the modal and also store the row data in the `selectedItem` state to use in the delete modal.

```
...
{
  icon: () => <Delete />,
  tooltip: 'Delete',
  onClick: (event, rowData) => {
    setSelectedItem(rowData)
    setOpen(true)
  }
}
...
```

Than you can conditionally render the `deletePrompt` in the same component by using the `open` prop

```
{open ? 
  <DeletePrompt
    open={open}
    handleClose(() => { // reset on close
      setOpen(false)
      setSelectedItem({})
    })
    content={selectedItem}
  .... // other props
  /> : null}
```

Finally, update your `DeletePrompt` component to remove the `open state` from there and use the props.

```js
export default function DeletePrompt(props) {
  const { content, open, handleClose } = props; // assignment
  const data_id = props.data_id;

//   const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

//   const handleClickOpen = () => {
//     setOpen(true);
//   };

//   const handleClose = () => {
//     setOpen(false);
//   };

//   if(props.button_click === 1){
//     handleClickOpen()
//   }

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
          {"Are you sure to Delete?"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            { content } // make sure, this is not an object. If its an object use some property of it.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} autoFocus>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Junaid Faryad this actually solved my issue. As I am utilizing .jsx there was a slight modification which I needed it to be done.
```
        {open ?
          <DeletePrompt 
            open={open}
            handleClose={()=>{
              setOpen(false)
              setSelectedItem({})
            }}
          />: null
        }
```
this was needed to be added instead of 
```
{open ? 
  <DeletePrompt
    open={open}
    handleClose(() => { // reset on close
      setOpen(false)
      setSelectedItem({})
    })
    content={selectedItem}
  /> : null}
```